# SQL SERVER Propietarios de un objeto

Tags: sql-server

Quisiera saber si hay alguna forma de conocer el propietario de un objeto en SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la vista/tabla `sysobjects` que está disponible desde SQL 2000

```
SELECT  so.name AS 'ObjectName',
    su.name AS 'OwnerName' 
    FROM sysobjects so 
    INNER JOIN sysusers su 
        ON so.uid = su.uid 
    ORDER BY 2,1
```

Esto te va a dar los `owners` de cada uno de los distintos objetos del database actual, eventualmente podrías filtrara por `so.id` si tienes el OBJECT_ID del objeto o `so.name` si tienes el nombre, siempre verifica también el `so.xtype` para estar seguro del tipo de objeto.

**Nota**: `sysobjects` es una vista que se mantiene por compatibilidad, lo correcto en versiones nuevas sería usar `sys.sysobjects`

Comment: Muchas gracias es lo que requeria saber.